"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" and xlib error when starting python web app on orange pi 5 debian bullseye 11
this is the whohle error
orangepi@orangepi5:~$ python3 /home/orangepi/v-link/V-Link.py 
Initializing backend... 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/hone/orangeps/v-Link/V-Link.py", line 9, in <module>     
from backend.adc  import ADCThread 
File "/home/orangepi/v-Link/backend/adc.py", line 9, in <module>    
import board 
File "/home/orangepi/- Local/Lib/python3.9/site-packages/board.py", Line 144, in <module>   
from adafruit blinka.board.orangepi.orangepi5 import * 
File "/home/orangepi/.local/Lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/board/orangepi/orangepi5.py", line 6, in <module>   
from adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.rockchip.rk3588 import pin 
File "home/orangepi/. local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/micrcontroller/rockchip/rk3588/pin.py", line 11, in <module> 
GPIOO_AO = Pin((0, 0)) 
File "/home/orangepi/. Local/Lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/libgpiod/libgpiod_pin_2_x.py", line 34, in _init_ 
self, chip = gpiod.Chip(chip id) 
File "/home/orangepi/,local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gpiod/chip-py". Line 58. in _init_ 
self._chip = ext.Chip(path) 
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied 
Exception ignored in: <function Pin._del_ at 0x7f88608b80> 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File. "/home/orangepi/.local/Lib/python3.9/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/libgpiod/Libgpiod_pin_2_x.py": line 38, in _del_.    if self._line_request:

AttributeError: 'Pin' object has no attribute '_line_request'  

So when I tried runnning the app as root the app starts and I get "Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0" : b'No protocol specified\n'
App starts only when I run it as root and xhost+ whithout xhost it throws xlib error

import threading
import time
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

from backend.server              import ServerThread
from backend.adc                 import ADCThread
from backend.canbus              import CanBusThread
from backend.linbus              import LinBusThread
from backend.browser             import BrowserThread

from backend.dev.vcan            import VCanThread
from backend.shared.shared_state import shared_state

class VLINK:
    def __init__(self):
        self.exit_event = shared_state.exit_event
        self.threads = {
            "VCan":     VCanThread(),
            "Browser":  BrowserThread(),
            "Server":   ServerThread(),
            "Canbus":   CanBusThread(),
            #"Linbus":  LinBusThread(),
            "ADC":      ADCThread(),
        }


    def start_thread(self, thread_name):
        thread_class = self.threads[thread_name].__class__

        if not self.threads[thread_name].is_alive():
            self.threads[thread_name] = thread_class()
            thread = self.threads[thread_name]
            thread.daemon = True
            thread.start()
            shared_state.THREAD_STATES[thread_name] = True
            print(f"{thread_name} thread started.")
        else:
            print(f"{thread_name} thread is already running.")


    def stop_thread(self, thread_name):
        thread = self.threads[thread_name]
        if thread.is_alive():
            print(f"Stopping {thread_name} thread.")
            thread.stop_thread()
            thread.join()
            shared_state.THREAD_STATES[thread_name] = False
            print(f"{thread_name} thread stopped.")

    def toggle_thread(self, thread_name):
        if shared_state.THREAD_STATES[thread_name]:
            self.stop_thread(thread_name)
        else:
            self.start_thread(thread_name)

        self.print_thread_states()

    def join_threads(self):
        for thread_name in self.threads:
            self.stop_thread(thread_name)

        for thread_name, thread in self.threads.items():
            if thread.is_alive():
                thread.join()
                shared_state.THREAD_STATES[thread_name] = False
        print("Done.")

    def process_toggle_event(self):
        if shared_state.toggle_can.is_set():
            self.toggle_thread("Canbus")
            shared_state.toggle_can.clear()
            
        if shared_state.toggle_adc.is_set():
            self.toggle_thread("ADC")
            shared_state.toggle_adc.clear()

        if shared_state.toggle_browser.is_set():
            self.toggle_thread("Browser")
            shared_state.toggle_browser.clear()


    def process_exit_event(self):
        if self.exit_event.is_set():
            self.exit_event.clear()
            shared_state.toggle_browser.set()
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.exit(0)

    def print_thread_states(self):
        if(shared_state.isDev):
            for thread_name, thread in self.threads.items():
                state = "Alive" if thread.is_alive() else "Not Alive"
                print(f"{thread_name} Thread: {state}")



def clear_screen():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')

def non_blocking_input(prompt):
    try:
        return input(prompt)
    except EOFError:
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    vlink = VLINK()

    vlink.start_thread("Server")

    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "dev":
        shared_state.isDev = True
        choice = non_blocking_input("Simulate CAN-Bus? (Y/N): ")
        if choice.lower() == 'y':
            shared_state.vCan = True
            print("Starting VCAN...")
            vlink.toggle_thread("VCan")

        choice = non_blocking_input("Start on Vite-Port 5173? (Y/N): ")
        if choice.lower() == 'y':
            shared_state.isFlask = False

        choice = non_blocking_input("Start in Kiosk mode? (Y/N): ")
        if choice.lower() == 'n':
            shared_state.isKiosk = False

    vlink.start_thread("Canbus")
    time.sleep(.1)
    vlink.start_thread("ADC")
    time.sleep(3)
    vlink.start_thread("Browser")

    vlink.print_thread_states()

    try:
        while(True):
            vlink.process_toggle_event()
            vlink.process_exit_event()
            time.sleep(.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nExiting... Stopping threads.")
            #vlink.join_threads()
            sys.exit(0)

and this is the app i tried to start

Lots of Error output. But what are you trying to do. Perhaps post the script to?

ok i will do that
